# Hibernate criteria query throws an exception

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I want to get all shops with rating avg less than 4.2. But my criteria throws ClassCastException. I have the following criteria query.

```
double temp = 4.2;
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Shop.class, "s");
DetachedCriteria avg = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Rating.class, "r")
                .setProjection(Projections.avg("r.value"))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("r.shopId", "s.id"));
criteria.add(Subqueries.gt(temp, avg));
```

My entities:

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "shop")
public class Shop implements LazyClonable<Shop> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @Embedded
    private Location location;

    @Lob
    private String description;

//...getters and setters
}

@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "rating")
public class Rating implements LazyClonable<Rating> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private Float value;
    private String comment;

    @Transient
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Shop.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "shop_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Shop shop;

    /** foreign key */
    @Column(name = "shop_id")
    private Integer shopId;

//...getters and setters
}
```

And it throws the exception. Why? What I am doing wrong?
Exception stack trace:

```
Mar 29, 2015 4:14:52 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.IntegerTypeDescriptor.unwrap(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:1995)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:1966)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1901)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1682)
```

...

I have changed query to native SQL but still getting the same exception:

```
    criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(
            "(SELECT avg(r.value) FROM rating r WHERE s.id = r.shop_id) < ?", temp, DoubleType.INSTANCE));
```

Answer (score 4):

With:

```
Restrictions.eq("r.shopId", "s.id")
```

you check if the `shopId` is equal to string value `"s.id"`. But `shopId` is an integer column and `"s.id"` is a string value. So, it's normal you get an exception. Also it isn't want you want. You can't check equality between columns this way. Instead, use:

```
Restrictions.eqProperty("r.shopId", "s.id")
```